Apache automatically adds an 204 to the end of link when reverse proxying another site
I have an site a.example.com, and another site b.example.com.
I tried to set up a reverse proxy on a.example.com using Apache2, so that when I access a.example.com, the server would access b.example.com and forward the contents to user, with these:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName a.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://b.example.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://b.example.com/
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName a.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPass / https://b.example.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://b.example.com/
    SSLCertificateFile     /etc/certs/a.example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/certs/a.exmaple.com/privkey.pem
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_engine.log
    LogLevel debug

</VirtualHost>

But I only gets an 503 when accessing it. The logs shown that an "204" was somehow attached to the request:
[client] AH00944: connecting https://b.example.com/index.php/204  to b.example.com:443

Why would this even happen? Thanks in advance.

Your configuration doesn't match the log line. For example, there's an index.php in the destination too. Check you haven't already defined a (virtual) host for server name a.example.com

That index.php was automatically added by the remote host b.exmaple.com, which indicates that a.exmaple.com was able to connect to it (and I can verify that by checking the logs on b side). The only thing wrong would be the 204 suffix, in my opinion
